# Как найти значение из json, что-бы увеличить его на 1

Tags: javascript, json

Подскажите, как найти 'currentPeople' в функции добавления 'singUpBtn.addEventListener', когда 'currentPeople' взяты из json, что-бы увеличивалось количество на +1.

HTML

```
    <h1>Расписание занятий</h1>
    <div class="lessons-box"></div>
```

JS

```
async function fetchData() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('data.json');
        if (!response) {
            throw new Error('Не удалось обработать data.json');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        const lessonsBox = document.querySelector('.lessons-box');

        data.forEach(({id,title, date, clock, maxPeople, currentPeople}) => {
            const lessonsEl = `
                <div class="lesson-item" id="${id}">
                    <h3 class="title">${title}</h3>
                    <p class="date">Дата проведения - ${date}</p>
                    <p class="clock">Начало занятий -${clock}</p>
                    <div>
                        <p>Максимальное количество участников</p>
                        <p class="max-people">${maxPeople}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="current-people-box">
                        <p>Текущее количество участников</p>
                        <p class="count-people">${currentPeople}</p>
                    </div>
                    <button class="sing-up">Записаться</button>
                    <button class="сancel-recording">Отменить запись</button>
                </div>
            `;
            lessonsBox.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', lessonsEl)
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    };

    const singUpBtn = document.querySelector('.sing-up');
    const сancelRecordingBtn = document.querySelector('.сancel-recording');
    const countPeople = document.querySelector('.count-people');
    
    let count = 1;

    singUpBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const currentPeopleBox = document.querySelector('.current-people-box');

    })

    сancelRecordingBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    })
};

fetchData();
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Занятие по батскетболу",
        "date": "20 сентября",
        "clock": "18:00",
        "maxPeople": 10,
        "currentPeople": 7
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Занятие по футболу",
        "date": "21 сентября",
        "clock": "19:00",
        "maxPeople": 11,
        "currentPeople": 8
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Занятие по волейболу",
        "date": "19 сентября",
        "clock": "17:30",
        "maxPeople": 12,
        "currentPeople": 10
    }
]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проще всего, когда создаются html элементы в цикле, повесить нужный обработчик на кнопку, чем потом выискивать в dom нужное. Да и querySelector возвращает первый попавшийся элемент.